# Create rigid part on a cloth object

Tags: cloth-simulation

Is it possible to create a rigid part that react to physics on a cloth object ?

For exemple in the following image i've put the right part of the mesh as fully pinned, and put a monkey head under the mesh.
I'd like for the highlighted part to be rigid, not bend at all and keep its form.

[image: Exemple]

I've tried to add springs or change the pinning values also touched the property weights, am i missing something or did i not change the values correctly, if possible ?

[image]

Comment: why don't you just pin all that vertices on the left/lower part too?

Comment: @John MC, I think he wants the left part to be rigid but not stay in place

Comment: yes, i want the left part to be able to move with physics, not staying in place

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, kinda, look what I've done:

[image]

So, I started with your setup, and made 2 objects to be parented to corners (Using Vertex Parent (Ctrl+P in edit mode)) and 1 long object in the middle (also vertex parent):

[image]

Then I added track to constraints to rotate the long object:

[image]

So that the rotation of central piece is now like interpolated between positions of 2 corner pieces.

So the last part: I duplicated cloth, add the opposite corner to the Pin vertex group, and added a new vertex group with only the opposite corner to be driven by position of central piece using Hook modifier:

[image]

Order of modifier and cloth is important!

[image]

Finally, original cloth should be hidden from view and render. The method is not perfect, but I would like to see something better

Comment: Thanks !!, it works though it's quit tedious to do and it can cause some clipping.

Comment: As I said, it was not perfect